# java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out + google directory , admin sdk API

Tags: credentials, google-api-client, socketexception, service-accounts

I am getting the berlow error while using the service account.
    The same code works well in local and iam able to create the credentials using service account.

```
....Error Snapshot : 
aused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(SSLSocketImpl.java:618)
        at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:175)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:378)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:473)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.<init>(HttpsClient.java:270)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.New(HttpsClient.java:327)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:191)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:931)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:177)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1090)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:250)
        at com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpRequest.execute(NetHttpRequest.java:77)
        at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:965)
        at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenRequest.executeUnparsed(TokenRequest.java:283)
        at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenRequest.execute(TokenRequest.java:307)
        at com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredential.executeRefreshToken(GoogleCredential.java:269)
```

Comment: Code Snapshot  ------>> GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder() .setTransport(TRANSPORT) .setJsonFactory(jsonFactory) .setServiceAccountId("SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL") .setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File( new java.io.File("SERVICE_ACCOUNT_PKCS12_FILE_PATH")) .setServiceAccountScopes(scopes) .setServiceAccountUser("abc@xyz.com").build();

Comment: I have got the answer but somehow not able to post it... I will post it once i m given the access

Answer (score 3):

Try the following ...

1. Set the proxy in the linux box.
2. While creating storage - new NetHttpTransport() provide your own way to create the socket and add the proxy in the transport.

Example code ...

```
public HttpClient myHttpClient() throws Exception {

        SchemeRegistry schemeRegistry = new SchemeRegistry();
        //SetRegisrty for both HTTP and HTTPS - Check google for this.
        schemeRegistry.register(new Scheme("http", PlainSocketFactory
                .getSocketFactory(), YOUR_PROXY_PORT));
        schemeRegistry.register(new Scheme("https", SSLSocketFactory
                .getSocketFactory(), 443));

        HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
        HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(params, 30 * 1000);  // SET the timeout
        HttpProtocolParams.setVersion(params, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);
        ClientConnectionManager connManager = new ThreadSafeClientConnManager(
                params, schemeRegistry);
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(connManager,
                params);
        try {
            int proxyPort = YOUR_PROXY_PORT;
            String proxyHost = "YOUR_PROXT_HOST_NAME";
            if (proxyPort > 0 && proxyHost != null && proxyHost.length() > 0) {
                System.setProperty("https.proxyHost", proxyHost);
                System.setProperty("https.proxyPort", proxyPort + "");
                System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", proxyHost);
                System.setProperty("http.proxyPort", proxyPort + "");
                HttpHost proxy = new HttpHost(proxyHost, proxyPort);
                httpClient.getParams().setParameter(
                        ConnRoutePNames.DEFAULT_PROXY, proxy);
            }
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            System.out.println("Proxy error here");
        }
        return httpClient;
    }


    public static HttpTransport myNetHttpTransport()
                throws Exception {
            return new ApacheHttpTransport(myHttpClient());
        }
```

use .setTransport(myNetHttpTransport()) instead of NetHttpTransport() .

we spent long time on this. but as of now this seems to be working. Please let me know if any help in this...